# How can I reset an objects position, for real this time

Tags: transforms, origin

I have a recurring problem whenever i try to to something advanced in blender.

Whenever i am trying to rotate array around an empty or setup particle systems i will allways get an offset unless i am working in the world origin. I know i have to apply transforms and origins and have axes aligned properly but it does not seem to help.

I end up allways having to make a new file with everything in the world origin and exporting to my project file. How come i cannot just align origins to an arbitrary cordinate and get the things to interact properly?

Does it have to do with transforms to deltas or something like that I have missed?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're talking about an Array with the Object Offset option, you don't need to put the empty at the workd origin, you need to put it at the same location as the object origin, but maybe share a file where we could see your problem: https://blend-exchange.com/